# {Tikz}{Tree} How to reduce leaves placement

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

Hello (and sorry for bad English...)

I am working on a Tex document to produce algorithmic diagrams : it is quite good for me except that I would like to be able to reduce space used by leaves (it seems that tree works with a grid and some empty cells could be reused).

Here is the code (the algorithm does nothing interesting, it's only to show possible cases):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
% styles
\tikzstyle{principal} = [draw,rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal=false,rectangle split parts=2,minimum height=5mm]
\tikzstyle{bloc} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20,  text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=5mm]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20,    text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{io} =[draw,trapezium,trapezium left angle=70,trapezium right angle=-70,minimum height=5mm]
\tikzstyle{op} = [rectangle, draw, text width=5em, text centered, minimum height=5mm]
\tikzstyle{sequence} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm, minimum height=5mm]
\tikzstyle{nop} = [ellipse,fill=red!5, node distance=3cm, minimum height=5mm]
% document
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=3cm, 
sibling distance=2mm, thick,scale=0.9, 
every node/.style={scale=0.9, font=\large}]
\Tree 
[.\node[principal] {\nodepart{one}\shortstack{Principal}\nodepart{two}\shortstack{entier i,j\\reel j}};
     [.\node[sequence] {POUR} ;
        [.\node[decision]{\textsf{chaque i de 1 a 4 pas 1}};]
        [.\node[sequence] {\textsf{repeter}};
        [.\node [io] {\textsf{j $\leftarrow$ LIRE()}}; ]
    ]
  ] 
  [.\node[op] {\textsf{i $\leftarrow 1$}};]
 [.\node [sequence] {TQ} ;
    [.\node [decision] {\textsf{($i <= 4$)}};]
    [.\node [sequence] {\textsf{repeter}};
        [.\node [io] {\textsf{ECRIRE i}}; ]
    ]
 ] 
 [.\node[sequence] {SI} ;
    [.\node[decision] {\textsf{($i <= 10$)}};]
    [.\node[sequence] {\textsf{si vrai}};
        [.\node[op] {\textsf{j $\leftarrow 10$}};]
        [.\node[op] {\textsf{j $\leftarrow 10$}};]
        [.\node[op] {\textsf{j $\leftarrow 10$}};]
    ]
    [.\node[sequence] {\textsf{si faux}};
        [.\node[op] {\textsf{j $\leftarrow 12$}};]
        [.\node[op] {\textsf{j $\leftarrow 12$}};]
        [.\node[op] {\textsf{j $\leftarrow 12$}};]
     [.\node[sequence] {SI} ;
        [.\node[decision] {\textsf{($i <= 10$)}};]
        [.\node[sequence] {\textsf{si vrai}};
            [.\node[op] {\textsf{j $\leftarrow 10$}};]
        ]
        [.\node[sequence] {\textsf{si faux}};
            [.\node[op] {\textsf{j $\leftarrow 12$}};]
        ]
     ] 
    ]
 ] 
]  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
Node placement could be closer to save space.
Is there a possibility for some leaves to be alternatively under or above each other?

Are there special parameters that would allow that?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You can control the distance with the keys `level distance=` and `sibling distance=` (distance between leaves).

Comment: Yes, you are right, I tried this, but "level distance" modify placement from a node to members, and "sibling distance" between brothers. As you can see, some nodes could be a bit more to the left to reduce the width of the entire diagram.

Comment: This is a perfect application for `forest` package which works on top of TikZ.

Comment: @percusse Do you know how to solve the error I found with using `ellipse`, `child anchor=north`, `parent anchor=south` and letting `forest` take care of the node sizes? (I've got an answer below but to really let `forest` lose, I had to take the `ellipse`s out and I don't know why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`forest` is much better at optimising the placement of nodes. Here is a comparison of the tree your code produces (on the right) and a first-pass attempt to create the tree in `forest`:

[image: <code>forest</code> *vs.* <code>tikz-qtree</code>: node packing]

## First Pass

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/forest,
  principal/.append style={rectangle, minimum height=5mm},
  block/.append style={rectangle, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, rounded corners, minimum height=5mm},
  decision/.append style={diamond, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, inner sep=.5pt},
  io/.append style={trapezium, trapezium left angle=70,trapezium right angle=-70, minimum height=5mm},
  op/.append style={rectangle, text width=5em, minimum height=5mm},
  sequence/.append style={ellipse, fill=red!20, minimum height=5mm},
  nop/.append style={ellipse, fill=red!5, minimum height=5mm},
  sfstyle/.append style={font=\sffamily\large},
}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    thick,
    draw,
    scale=0.9,
    align=center,
    child anchor=north,
    parent anchor=south,
    every node/.style={font=\large},
  }
  [{Principal\\\hline entier i,j\\reel j}, principal
    [POUR, sequence
    [{chaque i\\de 1 a\\4 pas 1}, decision, sfstyle]
      [repeter, sequence, sfstyle
        [{j $\leftarrow$ LIRE()}, io, sfstyle ]
      ]
    ]
    [{i $\leftarrow 1$}, op, sfstyle]
    [TQ, sequence
      [{($i <= 4$)}, decision, sfstyle]
      [repeter, sequence, sfstyle
        [ECRIRE i, io, sfstyle ]
      ]
    ]
   [SI, sequence
      [{($i <= 10$)}, decision, sfstyle]
      [si vrai, sequence, sfstyle
          [{j $\leftarrow 10$}, op, sfstyle]
          [{j $\leftarrow 10$}, op, sfstyle]
          [{j $\leftarrow 10$}, op, sfstyle]
      ]
      [si faux, sequence, sfstyle
          [{j $\leftarrow 12$}, op, sfstyle]
          [{j $\leftarrow 12$}, op, sfstyle]
          [{j $\leftarrow 12$}, op, sfstyle]
       [SI, sequence
          [{($i <= 10$)}, decision, sfstyle]
          [si vrai, sequence, sfstyle
              [{j $\leftarrow 10$}, op, sfstyle]
          ]
          [si faux, sequence, sfstyle
              [{j $\leftarrow 12$}, op, sfstyle]
          ]
       ]
      ]
   ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: first pass]

## Second Pass

This is not perfect but it turns more of the spacing and packing over to `forest` which results in a more compact tree. This did, however, throw up an error I'm unsure how to solve: the use of `ellipse`. If I try to tidy the tree with these styles, I get errors about exceeding TeX's maximum dimensions. If I try to `delay` the application of the node options (vaguely trying to follow an example on page 27), then everything goes nuts because I just get the node options literally stated in place of the node content. While I get ellipses, they are huge. I'm sure the solution will be obvious to a `forest` guru but for now, I've just gone with the shading. Alternatively, circles work fine. (Not clear why ellipses are problematic - trapezium: OK, diamond: OK, circle: OK, ellipse:??!!!??!!!). It seems to need minimum height etc. stated but it wants this for all the other nodes as well?!

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/forest,
  decision/.append style={diamond, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, inner sep=.5pt},
  io/.append style={trapezium, trapezium left angle=70,trapezium right angle=-70, minimum height=5mm},
  sequence/.append style={fill=red!20},
  nop/.append style={fill=red!5},
}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    child anchor=north,
    parent anchor=south,
    thick,
    draw,
    align=center,
    rounded corners,
    font=\sffamily\large,
  },
  [{Principal\\\hline \mbox{}\\[-1em]entier i,j\\reel j}
    [POUR, sequence
    [{chaque i\\de 1 a\\4 pas 1}, decision]
      [repeter, sequence
        [{j $\leftarrow$ LIRE()}, io ]
      ]
    ]
    [{i $\leftarrow 1$}, yshift=-1em]
    [TQ, sequence
      [{($i <= 4$)}, decision]
      [repeter, sequence
        [ECRIRE i, io ]
      ]
    ]
   [SI, sequence
      [{($i <= 10$)}, decision]
      [si vrai, sequence
          [{j $\leftarrow 10$}]
          [{j $\leftarrow 10$}]
          [{j $\leftarrow 10$}]
      ]
      [si faux, sequence
          [{j $\leftarrow 12$}]
          [{j $\leftarrow 12$}]
          [{j $\leftarrow 12$}]
       [SI, sequence
          [{($i <= 10$)}, decision]
          [si vrai, sequence
              [{j $\leftarrow 10$}]
          ]
          [si faux, sequence
              [{j $\leftarrow 12$}]
          ]
       ]
      ]
   ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: second pass]

If anybody knows how to use the ellipse properly, please leave a comment! Note that the conflict seems to involve the specification of `child anchor`, `parent anchor` with `ellipse` and without specifying height etc. for all nodes.

Comment: your solutions produce nice and clear diagram with compact code ! I will use the 2nd pass, it is more pleasant to read (code and diagram). **Thanks a lot, it is perfect for me !**